# ¿Cual es el uso del operador % en printf de variables en lenguaje C?

Tags: c

Estoy comenzando un curso en youtube de C.

Y muestran que para imprimir los valores de las variables es necesario utilizar este operador `%`.

ejemplo:

```
int suma, a, b;
a=2;
b=3;
suma=a+b;
printf("El valor de la suma es %i", suma);
```

En caso de entero `%i`, float `%f`y char `%c`

Quisiera saber que otros usos tiene este operador y que atributos tiene dependiendo el valor, pues vi que podía delimitar los decimales mostrados usando `%.1f` o `%.2f`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

En el contexto que defines el `%` no es un operador sino un *especificador de formato*.

En C los especificadores de formatos son los que le dicen a las funciones *variadicas* el tipo de argumento con el que irá a trabajar.

En el caso más simple:

```
printf("%s\n", "hola mundo");
```

Le dice al compilador que optimice la llamada a la función `printf` para un argumento de tipo `char *`.

Los especificadores de formato más comunes pueden ser:

```
- %d o %i: Especifican un entero con signo.
- %u     : Especifican un entero sin signo.
- %p     : Direccion de un puntero u dato.
- %lld   : Especifica un entero largo (long long). [*]
- %llu   : Entero largo sin signo (unsigned long long) [*]
- %s     : Especifica que el parametro es un puntero a un arreglo de caracteres.
- %c     : Un caracter.
- %x     : Especifica un valor hexadecimal.
- %%     : Muestra un literal de porcentaje.
- %f     : Imprime un float o double.
```

*: Estos especificadores pueden estar fuera de estándar.

Fuera de este contexto, es un operador de módulo y sirve para obtener el residuo de una division.

---

**EDIT:**

Adicionalmente, como he mencionado en el principio, es un especificador de formato, tambien pueden utilizarse para rellenar espacios con ceros o como desees:

```
printf("%X es lo mismo que %02X", 0x0a, 0x0a);
```

Esto dara como resultado:

```
A es lo mismo que 0A
```

O tambien:

```
printf("%.03f es un float!\n", 0.250554);
```

Este ultimo limita a imprimir los 3 primeros lugares despues del punto decimal en un `float`.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Sentí que faltaba algo de información en esta respuesta, la cual está ahora presente en esta edición y es que los especificadores de formato tienen cierta magia por dentro.

Organicemos esto por tipos:

- `char *` o *"C-String"*: Su especificador es `%s`, pero que pasa si hacemos: `%.2s`?

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente string: `"Hola Mundo"` y hacemos:

```
printf("%.2s\n", "Hola Mundo"); // Resultado: Ho
```

La respuesta es: Se limita a imprimir solo 3 caracteres del parametro actual; de igual forma se puede utilizar para espaciar las cadenas:

```
printf("'%*s'\n", 20, "Hola Mundo"); // Resultado: '         Hola Mundo'
```

¿Y si los mezclamos?

```
printf("'%*.2s'\n", 20, "Hola Mundo"); // Resultado: '         Ho'
```

Como se puede apreciar, todo el formato de una cadena es posible en C.

El caracter `*` dentro de un especificador de formato, debe incluir un parámetro adicional en la llamada a la función para especificar su valor, como en los ejemplos mencionados anteriormente.

Aquí debajo una tabla con los posibles tipos de formato que se les puede dar a un parámetro, ver última referencia (Wikipedia):

```
Especificador   Lo que hace:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%07i            justificado a la derecha, 7 dígitos de largo, sin relleno
%.7i            largo mínimo de 7 dígitos, justificado a la derecha, rellena con ceros
%8.2f           tamaño total de 8 dígitos, con dos decimales
%.*f”',x,d)     tamaño predeterminado,x numeros decimales
%*.*f”,x,y,d)   tamaño igual a x, y numeros decimales
%s              cadena terminada en null
%5s             primeros cinco caracteres o delimitador
%.5s            primeros cinco caracteres, sin tener en cuenta el delimitador
%20.5s          primeros cinco caracteres, justificados a la derecha, con 20 caracteres de largo
%-20.5s         primeros cinco caracteres, justificados a la izquierda, con 20 caracteres de largo
```

El formato se aplica prácticamente igual para todos los tipos, pero aun así hay que ser cuidadosos.

---

Algunas referencias (En inglés):

- [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://www.crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Formatted-output-conversion-specifiers.html#Formatted%20output%20conversion%20specifiers)
- [Familia `printf`(C++Reference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)
- [`printf(const char fmt, ...)`](https://code-reference.com/c/stdio.h/printf)
- [Wikipedia, `printf`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf)

Comment: entiendo, y es por eso que sino se coloca no muestra la variable

Comment: Exactamente. Cabe mencionar que es comportamiento indefinido si no se especifica el mismo tipo en el parametro.

Comment: Cabe vez que editadas te ganas otro positivo, fuera genial que se pudiera votar varias veces jejeje.

Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: ¡Jajaja! Si te ha ayudado, considera marcar la respuesta.

Comment: Si estaba esperano respondiste en el tiempo de los 8 minutos y no me dejaba, por cierto como puedo iniciar un chat contigo? te tengo otra pregunta pero no cumpliria los estandares del sitio

Comment: Bueno, al personaje que ha proporcionado un -1, puede explicarnos la razón, así mejoramos todos :)

Comment: Cierto, podria especificar el porque? me parece muy completa la respuesta

Comment: También es bueno recordar que no existe un especificador concreto para diferenciar `float` de `double` porque al recibir `printf()` un número de argumentos variable para los valores a imprimir, C convierte implícitamente un argumento `float` a `double`. Por lo tanto, ya pases un `float` o `double`, `printf()` lo convierte a `double`, siendo el especificador `%f` suficiente para ambos. Para `scanf()` en cambio, sí hay diferencia de especificadores entre `float` y `double`.

Answer (score 2):

También se usa para el operador Módulo, que no es más que el resto de una división. Por ejemplo, aquí un pequeño trozo de código en C que dice si un número es par o impar:

```
int numero = 4;

if(numero % 2 == 0)
    printf("El número es par");

else
    printf("El número no es par");
```

Este debería sacar por pantalla "El número es par", ya que si divides un número par entre 2, el resto siempre va a ser 0. Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.