# Leer archivo y escribir archivos .txt en Lenguaje C

Tags: c

El siguiente es para ver cual es mi fallo al escribir un código porque efectivamente se que hay interacción (lectura) entre el programa y el archivo *.odt* que es el caso que he intentado, pero me trae el texto en simbolos extraños y no en letras. En el archivo que llamé *prueba.odt* y contiene una línea que dice "*probando lectura en C*", cree el código siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *archivo;
    char caracter;

    archivo = fopen("prueba.odt","r");

    if (archivo == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nError de apertura del archivo. \n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEl contenido del archivo de prueba es \n\n");
            while((caracter = fgets(archivo)) != EOF)
        {
        printf("%s",caracter);
        }
        }
        fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```

Se que el programa lee el archivo, pero como les dije anteriormente, trae un contenido no entendible.

Comment: Prueba a cambiar `%s` por `%c`. [Relacionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59594/4499)

Comment: Ese codigo funciona perfecto si lo que quieres es leer archivos txt, sin embargo para archivos odt, necesitas mucho más codigo, por lo que te sugiero que cambies el titulo a _Leer archivo .odt  y escribirlo en pantalla en Lenguaje C_ sería mucho mas claro. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, por ahora necesito trabajar con datos básicos... Es decir, en .txt, desconocía que era más complejo trabajar con .odt y .doc, ya será más adelante que aprenda a trabajar con esos.

Comment: Por ahora necesito aprender con .txt  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El formato de archivo **.odt**, analogamente al de Word **.doc** o **.docx**  no es un formato de [texto "puro"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_texto), sino que (en general [*]) es un formato binario que la aplicación correspondiente (en este caso, LibreOffice o similares) sabe interpretar. No puedes pretender leer byte a byte e imprimirlo a consola de texto y esperar que el resultado sea legible (que esperarías leer cuando el odt contiene letras en diferentes tamaños y formatos, por no hablar de imágenes incrustadas, etc?). Usa un archivo de texto puro (suelen tener extensión '.txt', aunque esto no es para nada necesario ni suficiente). Y antes de programar algo por el estilo, asegurate de saber qué contiene el archivo, examínalo con un [visor binario](http://www.proxoft.com/binaryviewer.aspx).

[*] De hecho, el formato puede ser de texto (si se usa XML), pero aun en ese caso no verías el texto que ves en el procesador de texto, sino un montón de ... "texto raro". Por otra parte, un arhicvo odt es casi siempre un archivo comprimido que contiene otros archivos dentro.  Puedes comprobarlo simplemente cambiandole la extensión a ".zip" y abriéndolo. También puedes adivinarlo si ves que los dos primeros bytes corresponden a los caracteres "PK" (reliquia de PkZip)

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu aporte! Soy principiante, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ademas estas utilizando fgets que corresponde a la lectura de un string, si quieres leer caracter por caracter utiliza fgetc. Ademas solamente lee texto plano y el formato odt no lo es