# Problema en punteros

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un programa que pida una frase y de ahi te imprima la frase y el numero de consonantes que tiene y lo que hice fue esto, pero al parecer tengo un error al leer la cadena y al imprimir el numero de consonantes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){


    char *pe;
    int tam;
    int i, aux=0;
    printf("Cuantos elementos tendra el vector:");
    scanf("%d",&tam);
    pe=malloc(tam*sizeof(char));
    gets(pe);
    printf("Contenido del vector dinamico:");
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf("%s ",pe[i]);
    }
    if(pe[i]!='a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'){
        for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
            aux++;
        }
    }
    printf("el numero de consonates de la frase es de: %s" ,aux);
    free(pe);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: es que en la cadena me la marca NULL no lee bien la cadena y no encuentro como arreglar eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Varios problemas

**Gets y el buffer de entrada**

La entrada por teclado hace uso de un **buffer** que es conocido como *stdin* la función scanf toma los valores de ese buffer que necesita y el resto los deja allí. Esto puede ser útil en ciertos casos, y siempre hay que tenerlo en cuenta a la hora de leer datos del teclado.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){


    char *pe;
    int tam;
    int i, aux=0;
    printf("Cuantos elementos tendra el vector:");
    scanf("%d",&tam);
    pe=malloc(tam*sizeof(char));
```

Cuando lees la variable tam  únicamente tomas el valor decimal tam, el resto de la entrada se queda en el buffer de entrada y cuando haces la llamada `gets` lo que recibe es el salto de linea. Por lo cual en reliadad no lees la cadena y pasa directo a procesarla.

Para evitar este error se coloca un limpiador de buffer, la funcion **fflush** indicando cual es el buffer que quieres limpiar, en este caso *stdin*

```
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(pe);
```

**Strings y Chars**

cadenas y cadenas de caracteres; el segundo error que tendrás una vez leida la cadena está al momento de imprimir la cadena, lo que parece que quieres hacer es iterar sobre cada elemento e imprimirlo, pero al momento de imprimir le dices a la función *printf* que imprima un `%s` que significa un *string* pero le pasa como argumento `pe[i]` que en este caso es un caracter. por lo tanto dile a la funcion printf que imprima un caracter con %c.

```
    printf("Contenido del vector dinamico:");
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",pe[i]);
    }
```

**Iteracion antes de llamar a i**

```
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
```

Si quieres hacer uso de la iteración de la variable i debes colocar el ciclo for antes, de lo contrario estarías tomando el valor que quedo almacenado en el ultimo ciclo for el cual es tam+1 y el cual es una posicion no accesible de tu vector `pe` lo cual inevitablemente conduce a un error.

**Correcto uso del condicional**

Lo que quieres es "Si PE[i] no es vocal incrementa el contador aux".

Pero lo que tienes es muy distinto `if(pe[i]!='a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u')` se puede "traducir" como:

si (pe[i] no es a) O e es verdadero O i es verdadero O o es verdadero ...

Cada una de esas variables sera verdadera porque no son NULL o 0, y por lo tanto ese loop siempre sera verdadero. debes hacer que cada condición sea una comparación

```
        if(pe[i]!='a'&& pe[i]!='e' && pe[i]!='i'&& pe[i]!='o'&& pe[i]!='u')
        {
           aux++;
        }
    }
```

**Printf y los tipos de variables**

Por ultimo  la variable aux es de tipo int y para imprimirla debes usar el tipo %d en el printf.

```
    printf("el numero de consonates de la frase es de: %d" ,aux);
    free(pe);
    return 0;
}
```

De esta manera me funcionó a mi. Espero que sea de ayuda.

## PD:

*Yo prefiero el uso de fgets sobre el uso de gets*

Con respecto al uso de % en printf puedes mirar esta otra pregunta 
[sobre los especificadores de formato en printf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59590/cual-es-el-uso-del-operador-en-printf-de-variables-en-lenguaje-c)

## IMPORTANTE

Gracias a un comentario de @NaCl he comprendido que siendo el buffer stdin un buffer de entrada y que la funcion fflush esta diseñada para limpiar buffers de salida, su comportamiento es indefinido, por lo tanto sobre todo en entornos Linux [usando fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin), se debe evitar hacer

```
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(pe);
```

En cambio recomiendo usar

```
    scanf(" %s",pe);
    //     ↑ colocando un espacio en blanco antes del especificador
    // scanf ignorará saltos de linea y espacios en blanco
```

Comment: gracias fue de mucha ayuda los consejos al final pude resolverlo con una funcion

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` es comportamiento indefinido.