# Error al ejecutar cuando se usa scanf

Tags: c

No puedo ejecutar ningún programa que lleve operaciones de cálculo en todos los compiladores que tengo instalados en mi Computador.

---

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num,tot;

    printf("Ingrese un Numero:");
    scanf("%d",num);
    tot=num+2;
    printf("El resultado es: %d");
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

---

Me aparece éste mensaje de error en todos los compiladores:
"El programa ha dejado de funcionar", acompañado de la opción "Cerrar programa".

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Por favor, pon el código que te falle y los mensajes de error como texto y no como captura de pantalla.

Comment: Según veo, si compila, que funcione es otra cosa... cambia `scanf("%d", num)` por: `scanf("%d", &num);`

Comment: Creo que es un error de los compiladores, todo código que lleve operaciones de cálculo no me los compila, el programa deja de funcionar.

Comment: no es error de los compiladores,  @NaCl ya te dio la respuesta te falta el & para usar un pointer y lograr la asignación

Comment: @Arkl Ahí tienes una respuesta :)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos...

Comment: Otra cosa, ¿Qué libros me recomiendan de C,C++ y Java?

Answer (score 3):

Tu código tiene 2 fallas:

1. `scanf("%d",num);`, la función `scanf` recibe argumentos para escanear valores por formato, que es el famoso `%d` que tienes entre comillas, `scanf` necesita la dirección de memoria donde este valor será asignado... Y de la forma que lo tienes ahora, le estás pasando el *valor* de la variable `num`.

Solución:

```
scanf("%d", &num); /* Con esto se arregla. */
```

2. `printf("El resultado es: %d");` la función `printf` cuando encuentra un `%*` *(Siendo el `*` un especificador de formato)*<sup>1</sup>, lo primero que hace es buscar el argumento corresondiente pasado a la función, el cual en tu caso, no está disponible y puede ser compotamiento indefinido<sup>2</sup>.

Adicional a esto, si pones el `%d` pero no pones la variable, no veras el valor de la variable.

Solución:

```
printf("El resultado es: %d", num); /* Pasa la variable num. */
```

Dejando el código completo:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num, tot;

    printf("Ingrese un Numero:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    tot = num + 2;
    printf("El resultado es: %d", tot);
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

He probado el código que he puesto anteriormente y me funciona perfectamente *(Ubuntu 14.04)* y este es el resultado que arroja utilizando 5 como número introducido:

```
Ingrese un Numero:5
sh: 1: PAUSE: not found
El resultado es: 7
```

Como se ve en la segunda línea, `sh: 1: PAUSE: not found` es debido a que `PAUSE` no está disponible en Linux, sólo es válido en Windows.

<sup>1</sup>: Referencia: [¿Cual es el uso del operador % en printf de variables en lenguaje C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59594/4499)
<sup>2</sup>: Si bien puede funcionar en ciertas plataformas, en otras es comportamiento indefinido, pero si `printf` no encuentra un argumento sólo lo salta.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas indicar la dirección de memoria, en la variable `num` con el `&` que indica la dirección de memoria de la variable, poniendo `&num` dentro de la función `scanf();`