# Iterar un arreglo de caracteres en c

Tags: c, array, caracteres

Quiero imprimir cada elemento del arreglo pero me genera un `segmentation fault`

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char arreglo[3]={'c','f','d'};
  char *puntero;
  puntero=arreglo;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      puntero+=i;
      printf("El valor de puntero es %s \n",*puntero);
}

}
```

Si en `printf` en vez de poner `*puntero` pongo solo `puntero` osea asi

```
printf("El valor de puntero es %s \n",puntero);
```

Me imprime asi:

```
cfd
fd 
d
```

No sé en que esté mal.

Comment: Karina, no necesitas asignar el valor del array al puntero, puedes iterar en el mismo array, agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para iterar un arreglo de caracteres en c, puedes realizarlo iterando el array y usando `%c` para imprimir caracteres en C.

```
int main() {
   char arreglo[3]={'c','f','d'};
  //char *puntero;
  //puntero=arreglo;
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      //puntero+=i;
      printf("El valor del elemento: %d en el arreglo es: %c \n", i , arreglo[i]);
  }  
}
```

para tener como salida:

```
El valor del elemento: 0 en el arreglo es: c 
El valor del elemento: 1 en el arreglo es: f 
El valor del elemento: 2 en el arreglo es: d
```

Para más información acerca de como especifica el formato a imprimir puedes ver esta excelente respuesta de [@NaCl](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4499/nacl) :

[¿Cual es el uso del operador % en printf de variables en lenguaje C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59590/cual-es-el-uso-del-operador-en-printf-de-variables-en-lenguaje-c/59594#59594)

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar el puntero. Que obviamente se puede. Porque si estas haciendo un ejercicio con punteros; obvio que tienes que incluirlo.

Espero que todavia sea de utilidad.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char arreglo[3]={'c','f','d'}, *puntero;

puntero=&arreglo[0];

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {

      printf("El valor de puntero es %c \n",*puntero);
    ++puntero;
    }

}
```